# Android: Scroll View and Edit Text issue when typing into Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml, android-scrollview

I am trying to implement some windowed vertical scrolling (with a header and footer which I have created using 2 relative layouts)in part of my app that I am developing in android 4.0 and what I would like to do is allow a user to scroll down in a certain part of a page and input some data into some edit texts which is then submitted by the pressing the button (I have no problems with applying functionality to the button or getting data from edit text widgets).

However, When I try and input something into an edit text, the scrollview freaks out and either goes up or down and creates random duplicates of the empty edit text and every other widget that is on the screen at that time, either visible or hidden behind the header of the scrollview, meaning that they appear in front of some other widgets (eg imageviews and textviews) which are not in the scrollview.

This link here shows the problem that I have been having:

[image]

I understand that scrollview works in a linear layout which I have addressed in the xml code but I have no idea what to do next.

Can anyone help? I am really struggling with this and the other questions i have seen on this site that are similar to this are not really helping me

Here is the xml of my activity page:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hello.SecondActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >  


  <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="315dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

   <!-- Header aligned to top --> 
 <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="315dp"
         android:layout_height="35dp"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="355dp"
             android:layout_height="25dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:text="Scroll up to classify the contents of the image"
             android:textColor="#000"
             android:textSize="14sp" />
     </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/footer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:gravity="center" >

  <TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
/>
 </RelativeLayout>


<ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/scrollableContents" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_above="@id/footer"
 android:layout_below="@id/header"
 android:isScrollContainer="false"
 >


 <LinearLayout

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:orientation="vertical" >



     <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

         android:layout_marginTop="190dp"

         android:text="Humans in image" />


 <!-- this next relative layout is to get 2 things on the same line in the linear         layout-->
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
 android:text="How many mammals are in the following image?"

 />   
 <EditText   <!-- this is the edit text i am testing with-->
 android:id="@+id/editText1"
 android:layout_width="105dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:inputType="text"
 >


</EditText>



</RelativeLayout>  


      <Button <!-- back to linear layout with just one widget on each line-->
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="95dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"           
         android:onClick="loadNextImage"
         android:text="@string/classify" />
```

And here is the android manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hello.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hello.SecondActivity" <!-- this is the corresponding  activity-->
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest
```

Note that if there is something i have missed, please let me know and i will add it.